# Trying to create simple rectangle using separate class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create a paddle for a keep the ball from touching the ground game. I create a separate class with attributes, an object, an a function. The class is supposed to draw a rectangle, but it isn't. Could someone help, thanks.

Script.js

```
import Paddle from '/src/paddle'

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

const GAME_WIDTH = 800
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600)

let paddle =  new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT)
paddle.draw(ctx)
```

Paddle.js

```
export default class Paddle {
    constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
        this.width = 150
        this.height = 30

        this.position = {
            x: (gameWidth - this.width) / 2,
            y: gameHeight - this.height - 10,
        }

    }

    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height)
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>JS Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width="800px" height="600px"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paddle.draw - can you confirm the ctx is correct within the draw function? it might be a scope issue?

Comment: Please show your html too. Did you set you `<canvas>`'s `width` and `height` **attributes** (not CSS style) to the same values as GAME_WIDTH and GAME_HEIGHT? Otherwise, your rectangle is far outside of the 300 x 150px default visible area.

Comment: I shared my HTML

Comment: You `<script>` needs a `type=module`  attribute. Your developer console should have thrown an error. However there is little chance that anyway facing the same root issue comes into this post, so I'm voting to close it as "typo".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Paddle Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <script type="module">
        import Paddle from './src/paddle.js';

        const canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        const GAME_WIDTH = 800;
        const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

        let paddle = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
        paddle.draw(ctx);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this code different from the OP?

Comment: I would like to use a different file instead of using script inside of the HTML file. i would prefer this because I want to practice using modules.